# How to insert quotes around a string in the middle of another string

Tags: python, regex

I need to change this string:

```
input_str = '{resourceType=Type, category=[{coding=[{system=http://google.com, code=item, display=Item}]}]}'
```

To json format:

```
output_str = '{"resourceType":"Type", "category":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://google.com", "code":"item", "display":"Item"}]}]}'
```

Changing the equal sign "=" to colon ":" is quite easy by using replace function:

```
input_str.replace("=", ":")
```

But adding quotes before and after each value / word is something that I can't find the solution for

Comment: Are you sure there isn’t a name for that format with an existing parser?

Comment: I'm not, but I couldn't find one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to surround with double quotes any sequence of characters that are not reserved in your markup. I also made a provision for escaped double quotes, and you can add more escaped symbols to it:

```py
import re
input_str = '{resourceType=Type, category=[{coding=[{system=http://google.com, code=item, display=Item}]}]}'
output_str = re.sub (r'(([^=([\]{},\s]|\")+)', r'"\1"', input_str).replace('=', ':')
print (output_str)
```

Output:

```
{"resourceType":"Type", "category":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://google.com", "code":"item", "display":"Item"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for the conversion.

```
def to_json(in_str):
    return in_str.replace('{', '{"').replace('=', '":"').replace(',', '", "').replace('[', '[').replace('}', '"}').replace(']', ']').replace('" ', '"').replace(':"[', ':[').replace(']"', ']')
```

this works correctly for the input you have mentioned.

```
print(to_json(input_str))

#output = {"resourceType":"Type", "category":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://google.com", "code":"item", "display":"Item"}]}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex is certainly more concise and efficient but, just for the fun, it's also possible using replace :

```
input_str = input_str.replace("=", "\":\"")
input_str = input_str.replace("=[", "\":[")
input_str = input_str.replace(", ", "\", \"")
input_str = input_str.replace("{", "{\"")
input_str = input_str.replace("}", "\"}")
input_str = input_str.replace("]\"}", "]}")
input_str = input_str.replace("\"[", "[")

print(input_str) #=> '{"resourceType":"Type", "category":[{"coding":[{"system":"http://google.com", "code":"item", "display":"Item"}]}]}'
```